# SKSpriteNode UIColor comparison

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to create a simple BreakOut game. 
There are blocks with different colors. I use these differences to set new attributes to the block. For example: A blue block will turn to a white block after the ball hits it. The white block will disappear...

My code so far:

```
let crashedBlock = againstBody.node! as! SKSpriteNode // againstBody is the body which touches the ball
switch crashedBlock.color {
case UIColor(red: 6/255,     green: 123/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1.0):
    crashedBlock.color = UIColor(red: 7/255,     green: 151/255, blue: 218/255, alpha: 1.0)
    break
case UIColor(red: 7/255,     green: 151/255, blue: 218/255, alpha: 1.0):
    crashedBlock.color = UIColor(red: 18/255,    green: 175/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1.0)
    break
case UIColor(red: 18/255,    green: 175/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1.0):
    crashedBlock.color = UIColor(red: 136/255,   green: 215/255, blue: 251/255, alpha: 1.0)
    break
case UIColor(red: 136/255,   green: 215/255, blue: 251/255, alpha: 1.0):
    crashedBlock.color = UIColor(red: 176/255,   green: 228/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1.0)
    break
case UIColor(red: 176/255,   green: 228/255, blue: 253/255, alpha: 1.0):
    crashedBlock.color = UIColor(red: 215/255,   green: 242/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0)
    break
case UIColor(red: 215/255,   green: 242/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0):
    crashedBlock.color = UIColor.white
    break
case UIColor.white:
    blocks.remove(againstBody.node!)
    againstBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    break
default: break
}
```

When I print the color of my block, I get a (1, 1, 1, 1), so that must be white. But it does not even get into my switch-case for white colors.

Comment: do not even check based on color, use some kind of identifier like `userData["colorType"] = 1`

Comment: also in swift you do not need to break cases

Comment: @Knight0fDragon could you show an example of using an identifier?

Comment: I prefer to use a enum of available color